# swing reuse panelchange class

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am writing a program that consists of a number of classes. At this stage, I am only doing the layout (Java Swing), and will add functionality later.

I added a menu bar that will appear on a JPanel with other items in each class (there is a reason I am doing it this way). I am calling classes from the class that contains my main() - it is called PanelChange. All it does (at this stage) is to replace the JPanel in this class with JPanels from the other classes, based on a user click on a menu item. This works perfect. Now I want to do this using the menu's from the other classes, and this is where I am running into trouble. When I instantiate the PanelChange class (object.item), it opens a new JFrame (this is probably because I instantiate a class that contains the JFrame). There certainly must be a way how I can access the functionality in my PanelChange class from the JPanels from other classes?

The following is a snipped from my PanelChange class:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new PanelChange();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        Object obj = event.getSource();
        if(obj.equals(book))
        {
            backPanel.removeAll();
            backPanel.add(panelBookings.backPanel);
            backPanel.repaint();
            backPanel.revalidate();
            this.setTitle("Manage Bookings");
        }
}
```

How do I use this functionality on a Panel from another class? Thanks!!!

Comment: `At this stage, I am only doing the layout (Java Swing), and will add functionality later.`, where `repaint();` and `revalidate();` <>/!= `CardLayout` :-)

Comment: Separate the UI menu from the model, have the menuBar static on the UI, allowing each view to add/remove content from it. Personally, I'd make a menu manger of some kind that facilitates the process, decoupling the elements from each other, but that's just me

Comment: Thank you, MadProgrammer, it works!